# Problema con una funcion de JAVA para mover y renombrar ARCHIVOS

Tags: java

Necesito que esta funcion:

```
public static void moveFile(String origen, String destino, String nombreCarpeta) {
    try {
        File ficheroOrigen = new File(origen);
        File carpetaDestino = new File(destino);
        
        // Crear la ruta de la carpeta destino
        File carpetaStringNombre = new File(carpetaDestino, nombreCarpeta);
        
        // Verificar si la carpeta con el nombre proporcionado existe
        if (!carpetaStringNombre.exists()) {
            carpetaStringNombre.mkdir(); // Crear la carpeta con el nombre si no existe
        }
        
        // Mover el archivo dentro de la carpeta destino
        File ficheroDestino = new File(carpetaStringNombre, ficheroOrigen.getName());
        moverArchivo(ficheroOrigen, ficheroDestino);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error al mover el archivo: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

```java
private static void moverArchivo(File origen, File destino) throws IOException {
    Path origenPath = origen.toPath();
    Path destinoPath = destino.toPath();
    Files.move(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo movido correctamente.");
    System.out.println(destinoPath);
}
```

Haga lo siguiente:
Se seleccione un archivo, y se le pase a la funcion moveFile la direccion de ese archivo y la direccion de una carpeta destino llamada pdfs (por ejemplo)
y un nombre de la carpeta llamada hola ( por ejemplo)

de modo que quede asi:

pdfs -> hola -> archivo.pdf

si la carpeta hola no existe, que cree una nueva. ademas necesito que archivo.pdf sea renombrado con el nombre que yo quiera

Ya he probado de todo, y no funciona nada

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene algunos problemines...
La siguiente linea está de más:

```
File ficheroDestino = new File( carpetaStringNombre, ficheroOrigen.getName() );
```

la linea:

```
File carpetaStringNombre = new File( carpetaDestino, nombreCarpeta );
```

ya hizo el trabajo, pero además, te arrojaba un directorio tipo:
`"home/carpetaDestino/home"`, o algo así, que, obviamente, es imposible de manejar.

tu método debería quedar así:

```
public void moveFile( String origen, String destino, String nombreCarpeta ) {
   try {
      File ficheroOrigen = new File( origen );
      File carpetaDestino = new File( destino );

      // Crear la ruta de la carpeta destino
      File carpetaStringNombre = new File( carpetaDestino, nombreCarpeta );

      // Verificar si la carpeta con el nombre proporcionado existe
      if( !carpetaStringNombre.exists() ) {
            
            // acá hacemops una sutil modificación para que cree multiples carpetas
            // cambiamos "mkdir" por "mkdirs"
         carpetaStringNombre.mkdirs(); // Crear la carpeta con el nombre si no existe
      }

      // Mover el archivo dentro de la carpeta destino
      moverArchivo( ficheroOrigen, carpetaStringNombre );
   }
   catch( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( "Error al mover el archivo: " + e.getMessage() );
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, Muchas Gracias

Comment: Un placer maestro!!